# html css table from xslt

Tags: html, css

Im generating a table from a xslt transformation using xslt-for-each loops

The table it creates have 2 columns where I need the first 2 to be 100% width. The execption is for cetain rows I need to create a row with colspan=2 and these rows must be able to grow more than 100%

This works, but scroll bar doesnt show, or shows with overflow:scroll but is then disabled:

```
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;border:1px solid black;">Text</td>
        <td style="width:50%;border:1px solid black;">More text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><div style="overflow:visible;float:left">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeEndofText.</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or is there maybe a way in an xsl for-each to do
Start table element
xsl-if test="something"
write end table element
Then create the colspan="2" row as its own table, then write a begin table element to continue with normal rows
The xsl throws errors for non matching elements.

Comment: How about a three-column table, using the third for overflow?

Comment: I did try but everytime the colspan=3 expanded it also grew the width of the lines with 3 seperate columns. how should I add the overflow or no-overflow to all the columns in this scenario ?

Comment: The table-with in this case will be equal for each row, so you'd get a joib styling so that the third columns have no border etc, and also enforcing width of the two columns.

Comment: Another solution that just came to min is to wrap the content in a div, take it out of the document flow (`position:relative`) and have it be as wide as it needs to be.

Comment: If you want the row spanning two columns to have a scrollbar when > 100%, change overflow:visible to overflow: auto.

Comment: With overflow:scroll, IE 9 shows scrollbar but as disabled. Chrome and FireFox always shows the scroll bar correct.